# Akka service should be reported as unhealthy if it is unable to connect to a Kafka cluster or database

Tags: apache-kafka, akka, akka-http, akka-cluster

By default all readiness checks are hosted on /ready and liveness checks are hosted on /alive.

If akka service is unable to connect to Kafka cluster, then the service should report as unhealthy.

What configuration do we need to add in akka so that health endpoint can report as unhealthy when cluster goes down?

Currently service reports healthy even if cluster goes down. It returns Ok.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to update your healthcheck endpoint to call Kafka API.

For example, you could use [`AdminClient.describeCluster()`](https://kafka.apache.org/33/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#describeCluster--), [as I did in this PR for an Akka API](https://github.com/zalando-incubator/remora/pull/62)